# Custom Font Stopped Working After Re-Opening Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, fonts

I’m working on a project and when I opened it the font completely stopped working.
My code

```java
        private static Font vollkornBold;

        static {
            try (InputStream in = Program.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("TextBasedAdventure/src/main/assets/VollkornSC-Bold.ttf")) {
            vollkornBold = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, in);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What Causes the Error:

```
    titleAdventureLabel.setFont(vollkornBold.deriveFont(Font.BOLD,100))
```

The Error:

> java.io.IOException: Problem reading font data.
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont0(Font.java:1208)
> at java.desktop/java.awt.Font.createFont(Font.java:1076)
> at TextBasedAdventure/main.Program.(Program.java:27)
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.awt.Font.deriveFont(int, float)" because "main.Program.vollkornBold" is null
> at TextBasedAdventure/main.Program.(Program.java:113)
> at TextBasedAdventure/main.Program.main(Program.java:88)`

I tried retyping it, repasting the fonts incase they were damaged, moving the assets folder; but none of it worked. I might try Reinstalling Eclipse since it has a habit of breaking on my computer

Comment: Wrong path. That should be `Program.class.getResourceAsStream("/assets/VollkornSC-Bold.ttf")`

Comment: @g00se Thank you so much, I have no idea what broke it in the first place.